# Question on How to see my mobile's contact numbers in PC

Tags: contacts

I want to see my all contact numbers in my mobile on  my PC.

Comment: If you are syncing your device contacts with google you can use [Google Contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts). If not, you can [export your contacts](http://www.androidcentral.com/importing-and-exporting-contacts), copy the VCF file to your pc and view it in an editor programm

Comment: You can login to your GMail account, and then on the right top navigation bar change from GMail to Contacts, and you'll see them all there.

Comment: @FiN Doesn't work for me. Or for anyone else who decided not to sync his private data with Google :)

Comment: @Izzy well that's true. If your google account is not syncronized it wont work. :)

Comment: @FiN Yupp. And neither if there even is no Google account on the device at all :)

Comment: @Izzy Well yes, but most of the users of Android have Google account.
So if it helps for the one who have it but don't know it, I hope the comment will help tehm.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is lacking multiple details – e.g. what device you're using, what Android version it is running, whether or not you use Google Services to backup/synchronize your data. Let me sum up some possibilities for a "generic answer":

- If your contacts are synchronized with Google Services: Take your browser to [Google Contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts) (or to [Gmail](https://mail.google.com/) and switch to Contacts from there), so your contacts are displayed in your web browser. You even can edit them there.
- Alternatively, open your *Contacts* app on your Android device, use *Menu › Import/Export › Export to SD card* to have all your contacts exported into a file using the [VCard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vcard) format. Transfer that file to your PC, and you can open it in almost all apps dealing with contacts (e.g. Outlook on Windows, or Evolution on Linux, or Thunderbird on any OS).
- Alternatively, if your PC is running Windows, you can install [MyPhoneExplorer](http://www.fjsoft.at/en/) to it (and the [MyPhoneExplorer Client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client) on your Android device). This not only allows you to see your contacts, but also to synchronize them (and your calendars) with your Windows PC, and much more.
- Alternatively, use some [remote management app](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/various_remotemanagement) which can be accessed via Web browser.